# Remove "Add To Carts" button in certain categories on Magento2

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I'm a noob when it comes to PHP.

However, my employer is asking me to hide the "Add To Cart" button for products in certain categories. I'm wondering if any of you could take a look and help me solve the problem

I appreciate any help you may be able to offer. Unfortunately this task is above my head and the other answers on this don't clearly specify what I need to change.

```html
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/** @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View */
?>


<?php
$helper                  = $this->helper("Lof\RequestForQuote\Helper\Data");
$enable = $helper->isEnabledQuote();
$disable_qty = $helper->getConfig('general/disable_qty');
$disable_qty = ($disable_qty !==null)?(int)$disable_qty:0;
$disable_addtocart = $helper->getConfig('general/disable_addtocart');
$disable_addtocart = ($disable_addtocart !==null)?(int)$disable_addtocart:0;
$enable_addtoquote = $helper->getConfig('general/enable_addtoquote');
$enable_addtoquote = ($enable_addtoquote !==null)?(int)$enable_addtoquote:1;
?>
<?php $_product = $block->getProduct(); ?>
<?php if ($enable && $disable_addtocart && ($enable_addtoquote || ($_product->hasData('product_quote') && $_product->getData('product_quote')))) {
    ?>
<div class="box-tocart">
    <div class="fieldset">
        <?php if ($block->shouldRenderQuantity() && !$disable_qty): ?>
        <div class="field qty">
            <label class="label" for="qty"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Qty') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="number"
                       name="qty"
                       id="qty"
                       value="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>"
                       title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Qty') ?>"
                       class="input-text qty"
                       data-validate="<?= $block->escapeHtml(json_encode($block->getQuantityValidators())) ?>"
                       />
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <div class="actions">
            <?= $block->getChildHtml('', true) ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php if ($block->isRedirectToCartEnabled()) : ?>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#product_addtocart_form": {
            "Magento_Catalog/product/view/validation": {
                "radioCheckboxClosest": ".nested"
            }
        }
    }
</script>
<?php else : ?>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#product_addtocart_form": {
            "Magento_Catalog/js/validate-product": {}
        }
    }
</script>
<?php endif; ?>
    <?php
 } else { ?>
<?php $buttonTitle = __('Add to Cart'); ?>
<?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
<div class="box-tocart">
    <div class="fieldset">
        <?php if ($block->shouldRenderQuantity()): ?>
        <div class="field qty">
            <label class="label" for="qty"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Qty') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="number"
                       name="qty"
                       id="qty"
                       value="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>"
                       title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Qty') ?>"
                       class="input-text qty"
                       data-validate="<?= $block->escapeHtml(json_encode($block->getQuantityValidators())) ?>"
                       />
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <div class="actions">
            <button type="submit"
                    title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $buttonTitle ?>"
                    class="action primary tocart"
                    id="product-addtocart-button">
                <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $buttonTitle ?></span>
            </button>
            <?= $block->getChildHtml('', true) ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<?php endif; ?>
<?php if ($block->isRedirectToCartEnabled()) : ?>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#product_addtocart_form": {
            "Magento_Catalog/product/view/validation": {
                "radioCheckboxClosest": ".nested"
            }
        }
    }
</script>
<?php else : ?>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#product_addtocart_form": {
            "Magento_Catalog/js/validate-product": {}
        }
    }
</script>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php } ?>
```